# How do i get an page login access_token for a facebook page, that does NOT expire?

Tags: facebook, authentication, access-token, administrator

This is the problem:
I have to program an app, that is posting photos to a page on Facebook, which is not administered by the user, who runs the app.

I know that for the page login I have to get the administrators access_token, as described here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/   (section "Page Login")

Step 1: I log in as Page Admin.

Step 2: I fill in the App-ID, the redirect_uri and the scope as described.

Step 3: As also described, I copy the token in here: https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=TOKEN_FROM_ABOVE

After that I get a list of pages, i am the admin of. I can use the appropriate token and every user of my app can post to that page. But only until the token expires.

The problem is at Step 2. When i receive the access_token, the end of the line already says "&expires_in=5848". Changing to "scope=manage_pages,offline_access" does not help.

This way obviously my app is totally useless.
What am I doing wrong? What am I missing here? Why is offline_access not working here?

Any help would be so very very appreciated!

Thanks in advance of course.

Answer (score 2):

I just created a brand new app.  Ensured the deprecate offline access was enabled.  Went to explorer, found my new app in the dropdown, granted myself manage_pages, went to me/accounts grabbed one of the **page** access tokens, and then linted it.

Whew! 1 hour expiration. Just like yours.

I tried exchanging that 1 hour page token and I got an error from fb. Grrrr....

I went back to the **user** access token, and exchanged it for a 60 day one. Verified in the linter that it was a 60 day.  Went back to me/accounts and grabbed one of the **page** access tokens and linted it.  Suprise!  Got a 60 day token from there.

So the moral of the story is, you cannot exchange page tokens, only user tokens.  But with a 60 day user token you can get a 60 day page token.  :)